# Cant apply for next level rate limit Facebook marketing api

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I have to create script to create adsets and ads for a facebook campaign and I have to do it for a lot of items. For now, i can create every needed entity but there is a big problem, the rate limit. I reach it pretty quick (I can create like 15 items before getting a rate limit exception) and this is very limitating, creating eveything by hand is actually much faster... I want to apply to the next level of rate limitation but I can't. One of my coworker contacted someone from facebook and we were told we did not make any API call using my app ID. Since I am able to create a campaigns, adsets, ads... and we can see those in power editor  I don't understand what is going on.

[What my dashboard looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyZzX.png)

We will need to be able to create everything using the API really soon so, after some research, I try asking the question here. Did I miss something when creating my app ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to go through the official request to promote your app from a Basic level to a Standard level. The level for your app determines how heavily it is rate limited. Details here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access

It sounds as if you have not make your official request in app dashboard. It's possible we evaluated your number of API calls before you reached the threshold, or the data we are able to see on your API calls was from an earlier time period when you did not consistently reach the boundary.

You could also be hitting rate limits due to your error rates.

You can apply here, and if needed, reapply: https://www.facebook.com/business/standardadsapi?attachment_canonical_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fbusiness%2Fstandardadsapi